# How do I list all nodes created by the same author on a (custom) profile page?

Tags: views, nodes, users, blocks

In my setup each user has a profile page. The profile page is a custom content type (each user can only have one and they have to add it them selfs).

On this profile page I would like to list all nodes of a certain type created by the same user as the profile page.

How do I do this (in a views block preferably)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be the solution

https://www.drupal.org/node/1919622

Comment: This seems like the solution I was looking for. Thank you.